# Can we get the electron version of vscode from node js application or command prompt

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I am planning to detect the electron version of the vscode from node.js or command prompt.

I know from vscode we can get the electron version by running this command(`process.versions.electron`) in developer tools. But how can we get it from node.js application or from command prompt?

Comment: what do you mean by "command prompt"? also, the current command to use in devtools is `vscode.process.versions.electron`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the path of vscode and read the package.json file:
example:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\package.json`
there you will find the version in the `devDependencies` object

Comment: This is file path doesn't exist in my system

Comment: than look to the folder where you have installed vscode

Comment: Thanks...able to find it in C:\Users\rakhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\package.json